# Is there such a thing as a printed traveler emergency reference? if so, where can it be found?

Tags: planning

I have traveled a lot this year for work, both domestically and internationally. The amount of travel will double in 2016. I am so tired of losing charge / service on my phone and my pad going down. Is there such a thing as a printed traveler's emergency reference, which lists phone numbers for hotel chains, airlines, car rentals, major banks, etc.? If so, what is it called and where can I find it?

Comment: The phone book / yellow pages?

Comment: @jcaron The yellow pages are still around, but the phone boxes / booths they were attached to are an endangered species!

Comment: These booklets used to exist in the 70's and 80's but apparently not so much anymore. The list of the total 800 numbers for all western travel venues and banks only take up about 8 pages, so the tomb would not be so massive. Oddly enough, the total number of "western" airlines / hotel chains, etc. has decreased considerably since the 80's.

Comment: Just buy a very small USB power bank and use it if your phone dies.  But resist using it to watch more YouTube videos at the gate.  :)

Answer (score 7):

Simply type a list of the hotel chains, airlines and car rental firms you deal with, plus the banks you have accounts with, add their toll-free and collect call numbers.  Print out copies to put in your suitcase and briefcase/computer case.  Want to be doubly covered, reduce the font size down to as small as you can easily read, then print out a diminutive copy for your wallet/passport case.  Want to be totally covered, save a digital copy on your phone, tablet and cloud.

A list of ALL airlines, car rental firms, hotel chains globally (since you mentioned traveling international) would be massive.

Comment: These booklets used to exist in the 70's and 80's but apparently not so much anymore. The list of the total 800 numbers for all western travel venues and banks only take up about 8 pages, so the tomb would not be so massive. Oddly enough, the total number of "western" airlines / hotel chains, etc. has decreased considerably since the 80's.

Comment: @sharon I am curious how you figure the numbers have decreased?  Or perhaps better asked, what is your definition of "western" as that seems to play heavily into your query?

Comment: Definition of "western" here are companies based in countries that are based in a "western" nation; i.e. "western cultures. This generally includes most of Europe, the U.S., and Canada. Likewise, "eastern" refers generally to Asia. There are considerably less hotel chains and airlines now than there were in the 70's-80's, mainly due to mergers and buyouts. There are good, recent articles on this subject at Forbes and Bloomberg.

Comment: Many of the hotel chains which "merged" or were bought out are still operated as separate brands and in many still cases have their own reservation number.  And when you look at how many airlines have started up in recent years, the list will still be quite long.

Comment: Tom, I don't agree or disagree; I myself don't know enough on the matter to make original commentary. Your argument appears to be with the authors of supposedly authoritative articles. Recommend you check out (print editions) : "Where have All the Hotels Gone" - Bloomberg, Nov.-Dec. 2013,  "Consolidations in the Travel Industry" - Travel Weekly Sept. 2012, and "Do All Airlines Eventually Fade Away?" - Forbes March 2014.

Answer (score 5):

I have unexpectedly discovered an answer to my own question. Acco Brands of Dayton, OH, puts out a "Weekly / Monthly" Binder:  "At a Glance Executive," Item# 70-NX81-OS, that contains among many other things, as I expected, one large page that has all relevant travel 800 numbers and web addresses. This binder is available at some Office Depots and on many online venues.